# How to add third party analyzer to sonarqube?

Tags: c#, plugins, sonarqube, roslyn

What is the procedure for adding third party rules in sonarqube? 
I'm using Roslyn SDK and vs2017(c#)

Comment: For .NET projects, you just need a scanner for MSBuild which can be found [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild).

Comment: I used MSBuild 15.0 , sonar scanner  4.6.1.2049.

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop your own plugin in Java

see [example](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example)